# Spurious app crashes after making a web request on iOS 11 with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, ios11

We've had a few very bizarre crashes in our app recently. They are not reliably reproducable. The crashes have all occurred on **iOS 11** devices so far. Our app is written in **Swift 3.2**. We are using **Xcode 9.0.1** with the **standard build system** (not the new Swift build system). It seems that after performing a certain web request, the app crashes with the below stack trace:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  OurFramework                  0x105283e84 __swift_deallocate_boxed_opaque_existential_0 + 2588
1  OurFramework                  0x10528366c __swift_deallocate_boxed_opaque_existential_0 + 516
2  OurFramework                  0x10528b368 swift_rt_swift_storeEnumTagSinglePayload + 24748
3  OurFramework                  0x1052911cc swift_rt_swift_storeEnumTagSinglePayload + 48912
4  OurFramework                  0x1052133d8 __swift_memmove_array32_8 + 1336
5  OurFramework                  0x10521304c __swift_memmove_array32_8 + 428
6  OurFramework                  0x105292504 swift_rt_swift_storeEnumTagSinglePayload + 53832
7  Alamofire                      0x1057cac64 _T09Alamofire11DataRequestC8responseACXDSo13DispatchQueueCSg5queue_x0D10SerializeryAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGc17completionHandlertAA0biH8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_AA0biH0VyypG_Tg5 + 264
8  Alamofire                      0x1057ca3f8 _T0Ix_IyB_TR + 36
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x1860c5088 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x1860c5048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x1860d1b74 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1016
12 CoreFoundation                 0x1866e9eb0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1866e7a8c __CFRunLoopRun + 2012
14 CoreFoundation                 0x186607fb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
15 GraphicsServices               0x18849ff84 GSEventRunModal + 100
16 UIKit                          0x18fbdc2e8 UIApplicationMain + 208
17 OurApp                      0x104de98b0 main (main.swift:19)
18 libdyld.dylib                  0x18612a56c start + 4
```

We are using **Crashlytics** to track our crashes and I'm not sure if it's because of a symbolication issue that I don't see more info than this but the trace indicates that something is going awry during a web request. Our app uses **Alamofire** to make web requests. Results from our testing where this crash occurred also support this theory since the crashes always occurred right after the app made a request to our backend. Could it be that in iOS 11 something changed in the underlying NSURLSession that Alamofire uses? Maybe iOS 11 is using a different caching strategy or something that's causing alamofire to invoke our result completion handler in a way that causes this crash? Has anyone seen this kind of crash before? What do **__swift_deallocate_boxed_opaque_existential** and **swift_rt_swift_storeEnumTagSinglePayload** mean? Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Seeing a `__swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential` in tests (XCode 9.2, iOS 11.2, Swift 3.2) that I've never seen before (was fine with XCode 9.1, iOS 11.1).